# Display an image by generating a signed Url dynamically using express, EJS, Google Cloud

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have a helper function getUrl which checks for a specific file in my private Google Cloud Storage. If it exists getUrl returns a signed Url of the corresponding file.

[image: helper function]

The getUrl function carries a filename as an argument. The filenames are retrieved from my mysql database. Routes are initiated from index.js to ejs view.

[image: index.js]

I try to make use of the helper function in the ejs view in order to generate a signed Url and to render a remote image dynamically. But somehow the signed Url is not displayed as image source. Instead, my browser shows <img src = "[object promise]".

[image: ejs view]

[image: browser img src]

As I am at the very beginning of learning code, I hope my problem explanation is understandable. I appreciate every help that I get!